# How to use GRUB2 with UEFI for secure booting Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2

I have a mirco computer board such as BeagleBone black.How I can make secure boot of Ubuntu in it using Grub2 and UEFI?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use GRUB/UEFI with BBB.
You have to use U-Boot since that's the only officially (and actually) supported boot loader.

Please refer the [user guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_U-Boot_User%27s_Guide).

However, if you explain what kind of security you need, people here may suggest different solutions.